# Eclipse to IntelliJ IDEA: Create 'Run As' Configurations

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, intellij-idea

I have recently migrated from Eclipse to IntelliJ and am trying to create a run configuration for a Maven project I have imported. The instructions for Eclipse are fairly simple and are described below

To run the project, first create a run configuration:

```
1) Select project name and right click
2) Choose `Run As` then `Run Configurations`
3) Launch new configuration and enter the project's location as the base directory
4) Set the `goal` to run on a `localhost`. 
5) Click Configure button to configure the external maven location
```

My issue is at step 4. I am trying to create a `goal` for my Maven run but I can't seem to find the `goal` option anywhere. Is there a way to get this `goal` option? Alternatively what's the best way to run a Maven project in IntelliJ?

Comment: [This](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/working-with-server-run-debug-configurations.html) should explain it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to follow these step :

Go to File->settings->Application Servers, click +(green button) and your application server. Click Ok .

Run -> EditConfiguration -> Click `+`(green button) and select your application server, Under `Server` tab configure the port and other stand stuff(you can also issue maven goal like clean install in this tab so whenever you will launch your application maven will build the project) , then switch tab to `Deployment`, click  +(green button) and you will be presented with your artifact name which you want to deploy.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Is the process the same for external servers?

Comment: @Black Glad it helps, what precisely you mean by external servers?

Comment: no problem. I've figured it out so it was probably a stupid question.